# How to solve Pylint rating issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, lint, pylint

I'm trying to apply the Pylint rules on the following code:

```
class A:
    

    @staticmethod
    def r():
        

        query = {"get_data": {"$sum": 1)},
                             "value": True}
```

This is giving the result:

```
a.py:8:0: R0903: Too few public methods (1/2) (too-few-public-methods)
```

Any thoughts on solving this?

Comment: Just don't make this a class at all. A class with no internal state and a single staticmethod should not be a class. Just use a regular function.

Answer (score 1):

You could rethink / refactor this class but I don't think it's warranted.
It's sometime valid to have an API with a single entry-point. You can add a `pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods` if you think a pylint's message is too opinionated, or even in your pylint configuration file directly to disable for the whole project.

Disclosure : I'm a pylint maintainer, we're probably going to make this check optional because we think it's too opinionated.

Comment: Thanks for this great note. May I ask, where exactly I can the disable statement?

Comment: It should be in the same scope of the error if you disable locally https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/message_control.html#block-disables. But I advise you to disable it in pylint configuration directly https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/main/examples/pylintrc#L145

Comment: " but I don't think it's warranted. " It is absolutely warranted, this should absolutely not be a class at all, it doesn't make any sense for it to be - it has no internal state. It just has a single static method, so it should just be a function

Comment: It makes sense if you decided you wanted to use class for something for example django meta inner class raise this message. A class hierarchy for dependency injection that will only have a ``run`` function also raise this and will not easily be replaced by functions. See https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3512